# Entity Framework DbUdateConcurrencyException on Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

While loading some data from a 3rd party API, I was receiving a `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` from Entity Framework and no records were being inserted:

```
Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected
an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted
since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

Here's an example of the model class:

```
[Table("Events")]
public class StgEvent
{
    public Nullable<DateTime> WebServiceCallDate { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Lookup { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(510)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(510)]
    public string Client { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(510)]
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the load method:

```
public override void LoadToSqlEF()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext(ConnectionString, SchemaName))
    {
        context.Events.AddRange(Events);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The error description didn't really make sense because only data is being inserted.  I didn't see anything similar on StackOverflow, so I figured I would post my issue and resolution in case someone else has this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a down vote. Even though I've already figured this issue out and it was pretty simple, I thought it could be useful to someone in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong by running the sql profiler and noticed the EventId value wasn't being included in the insert statement.  Therefore, I realized I needed to add the `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` attribute to my EventId:

```
[Table("Events")]
public class StgEvent
{
    public Nullable<DateTime> WebServiceCallDate { get; set; }
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Lookup { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(510)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(510)]
    public string Client { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(510)]
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
}
```

Once the attribute was added, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem but the cause was in the data context object, which contained this line:

**this.Entry(resource).State = EntityState.Modified;**

This places the data context object which needs to be inserted, into a state which causes the database to refuse updating because it is "modified".

Just before saving the code hit the following line containing the lines above:

```
if (resource.Id == Guid.Empty)
{
    this.Entry(resource).State = EntityState.Added;
    resource.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    resource.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
    resource.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
else
{
    this.Entry(resource).State = EntityState.Modified;
    resource.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

I caused it by setting the GUID too early and the first part of the code never executed. The context was always "modified" even when new, which caused the problem.